# Can bootable devices be detected by admins?

Tags: boot, usb, monitoring

If I were to boot into an external USB disk on my work PC, what are the chances that it could be detected? With my limited knowledge on this I am pretty confident that any monitoring software on the totally seperate internal HDD will have no idea, but is there such a thing as "BIOS-level" monitoring that logs devices that were booted into for example? If such a thing exists, what kind of data would it log?

I'm not talking about network level monitoring here. Obviously any traffic on the company network can potenitally be logged.

I'm asking as I want to be able to boot into a seperate OS for doing homers/courses in my lunch break without doing it in my super locked down work OS. There's no real issue with doing that either, it just got me thinking about what's possible.

Comment: Don't do this. Get your own computer to do this on. We don't know the utilities your employer uses, and it's possible they may be able to tell this.